# verifying a domain using php

Tags: php

I have a member area, where they can add their domains and it will be displayed in the profile page..but now I want to add a verification process, just like google web-masters does..where they need to upload a certain file and so..
please tell me whats  the best way to do this ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Generate a token for each domain (sha-1 of domain or so), store it in your DB or what have you.
2. Generate a text-file containing the token on user request.
3. Ask the user to inform you to poll or poll every now and then to check the URL. This can easily be done by file_get_contents in PHP if fopen_wrappers are enabled.
4. The token is obviously compared to the token in your DB to make sure it wasn't just a random file present at a random domain..
5. Could be a good idea to check at some time interval if the file is still there, to keep someone from selling the domain but remain in control

It's not really black art as we can assume the user has access to its domain once any specific request which proves access can be fulfilled by the user. There's no real way to fool the system except doing some DNS-magic, or gaining entry to the webserver running on the domain, which is out of your control anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if that's the *best* way, but I think Google does something like this:

1. get user's domain name (e.g. "http://example.com")
2. generate unique code and store in db
3. tell user where to upload the code (e.g. something like "/verification.txt")
4. after confirmation, make a HTTP request for the code ("http://example.com/verification.txt") from own server to the user's server
5. compare the code you received to the code in the db

You may want to generate consistently the same code for the same domain.

Comment: .. or., alternatively, you may want to consitently generate a _different_ code for a domain (or consistently the same for a domain+user combo), as other users could possibly get more credentials / rights with a verified domain, and you may not want any old user to be able to get to that data if the real owner has signed up. It highly depends on the circumstances of the app you're verifying to.

Answer (score 1):

This question is convoluted. I think you need to spell out what you are looking for a little better.

EDIT #1:

Generate an md5 and give it to the user, tell them to put it on their domain and provide a URL to where it is. This could be in a txt file or anything.

Then read that file and check if the md5 string exists in there.

Actually I would come up with something slightly different than an md5. Maybe three of them, so that you reduce the chance they find it on some other domain and then give you that URL.

This can still be spoofed unless you nail down constraints, like it has to be a text file, the file must only contain the md5... etc.

Right now I can type in an md5 but it doesn't mean I control this website:

md5("i fooled you") = "0afb2d659b709f8ad499f4b87d9162f0"

But if I handed the URL to this answer, your system might accidentally think I have admin here.

I recommend creating a file and making them upload the file and give you the URL to it. But even that won't necessarily work because there are many sites where you can just upload something.

Maybe if it's a php encoded file that can execute? That's kind of a security flaw because I don't know if I would upload just anyone's PHP file. Typically if you don't have admin nobody is going to let you upload a php file that would work.

You might want to create a php call-home script but that's gonna be bad. People wouldn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way it could be done is:

1. Get the domain name
2. Generate a random code/string.
3. Sore this in your database
4. Make a meta tag and the random code in the content.
5. Use file get contents of the index page of the website.
6. Then search the page for the meta tag with the code sorted in the database.
7. If statement for success or unsuccessful.

The meta tag should look like this:

```
<meta name="site-verification" content="1010101010101010101010101010101010101010" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, just creating an md5-string for the domainname, letting the site owner put that in a meta-tag so you can check that would allready work fine ...